# .jar error while importing project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, jar, import, package

When I try to import any of the projects from below repository in Android Studio I get an error saying that ..\settings.jar cannot be found!

Repository: 
https://github.com/aporter/coursera-android/tree/master/Examples/TheAnswer

Answer (score 3):

first close the current projects if any; from file > close project. Then, from the main menu choose import project. If the gradle build failed (you can see it at the lower bottom left of android studio), then install all the sdk's from tools > android > sdk manager; specially the old ones. Then run an AVD and execute the app.